# pyinstaller failed to execute script python

Tags: python, tkinter, moviepy

i tried to run pyinstaller --onefile -w Converter.py it successfully installed but it says that it failed to execute script my script is this

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from moviepy.editor import *
from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()
root.title("mp4 to mp3 converter")
canvas = Canvas(width=230,height=100)
canvas.pack()
frame = Frame()
frame.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.1,relwidth=0.9,relheight=0.8)
def steps():
    messagebox.showinfo("HOW TO CONVERT","STEPS:\n 1, SELECT THE PATH OF MP4 FILE \n 2, PRESS CONVERT AND ENTER THE NAME OF YOUR FILE LIKE EXAMPLE.MP3")
def select():
    select=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="select path" ,title="open mp4 file" , filetypes=(("mp4 files","*.mp4"),("All files","*.*")))
    selector_path.set(select)
    messagebox.showinfo("mp4 ","you have now selected mp4 file")
def convert():
    m=str(selector_path.get())
    video = VideoFileClip(m)
    video.audio.write_audiofile(filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="select path" ,title="save mp3 file" , filetypes=(("all files","*.*"),("mp3","*.mp3"))))
    messagebox.showinfo("conversion complete","successfully converted to mp3")

select1=StringVar()
label1= Label(frame,text="MP4 LOCATION")
label1.grid(row=1,column=0)
selector_path=StringVar()
btn1=Button(frame,text="select" ,command=select, bg="black",fg="gold")
btn1.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

and there is no error with the code but this is the error when i run the exe file

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
 File "Converter.py", line 4, in <module>
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
 File "c:\users\nafi.desktop-q4u6hnf\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
   exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
 File "site-packages\moviepy\editor.py", line 87, in <module>
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'moviepy.audio.fx.all' has no attribute 'audio_fadein'
[7880] Failed to execute script Converter
```

Comment: Create the exe without `-w`, then run it in a terminal and see what the errors are.

Comment: Did you forget to copy the `root.mainloop()` to here or did you not use it ?

Comment: @CoolCloud i used root.mainloop()

Comment: You should prolly do what @acw1668 said and then paste the error code here

Comment: @acw1668 check the error i updated the question

Comment: The error stated clearly it cannot find `audio_fadein`.  Double check the version of the module used by running the script directly is the same as the one used by pyinstaller.